# Add value of variables from database to Tinymce

Tags: symfony, doctrine, tinymce-4

Is there any way I can add for example one of my user's name that comes from database to my Tinymce Editor? For example if I write username (username will be kind of reserved word) in Tinymce editor you will have possibility to choose one of the usernames that are in database. I'm using Symfony2 and doctrine for this project. Do you have any recommendation how can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: what have you already tried. do you have some code?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that is possible, I can think of at least couple of alternatives how you could implement this kind of feature. These both solutions require that you have a function create a dialog window with javascript that is populated with the username selection with the values from database.

1) If you really want it to work as described (i.e. when encountering 'username' string), you can listen to the onChange event on tinymce, and when encountering this, open the username selection dialog with javascript and update the editor contents accordingly if some username was selected from the dialog. This solution has several issues that you would have to address (i.e. how to manage where the username string was entered, how to handle cases where you want to have the actual username string, how to handle cases where you paste text with multiple username strings, etc etc)

2) Second, perhaps a cleaner solution would be to create a tinymce plugin ([tinymce: creating a plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin)). With this approach, you could implement a solution that would be most appropriate for your case, i.e. for example opening the dialog and entering the selected username to the cursor position (or opening the dialog for each existing username string and processing them one by one).

I haven't actually implemented this kind of feature, but I assume that it would be fairly straightforward to implement either one of these solutions.